# Identify the Marvel characters in this image

Tags: marvel

I recognize all the guys on the left and Apocalypse, but who are the rest?

Extra points for identifying that crab monster guy...

[image]

Comment: Bah, the provided image is too easy.  Let's have someone identify everybody from [this image](http://www.comicsbeat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/XMEN922015001_CVR_color_FINAL.jpg).  @DVK: This answers the middle part of your earlier comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

1. [Jubilee](http://marvel.com/universe/Jubilee)
2. [Bishop](http://marvel.com/universe/Bishop_%28Lucas_Bishop%29)
3. [Storm](http://marvel.com/characters/57/storm)
4. [Wolverine](http://marvel.com/universe/Wolverine_%28James_Howlett%29)
5. [Rogue](http://marvel.com/universe/Rogue)
6. [Gambit](http://marvel.com/universe/Gambit)
7. [Beast](http://marvel.com/universe/Beast_%28Henry_McCoy%29)
8. [Psylocke](http://marvel.com/universe/Psylocke)
9. [Omega Red](http://marvel.com/universe/Omega_Red)
10. [Exodus](http://marvel.com/universe/Exodus)
11. [Apocalypse](http://marvel.com/universe/Apocalypse_%28En_Sabah_Nur%29)
12. [Fabian Cortez](http://marvel.com/universe/Cortez,_Fabian)
13. [Bastion](http://marvel.com/universe/Bastion)
14. [Mystique](http://marvel.com/universe/Mystique)
15. [Trevor Fitzroy](http://marvel.com/universe/Trevor_Fitzroy)
16. [Brood](http://marvel.com/universe/Brood)